# How do you use variables in UDF's in mySQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, phpmyadmin, user-defined-functions

So i am trying to create a function in phpmyadmin using mySQL

So first i program it in SQL Server and then copy-paste it into phpmyadmin and when i try to insert the function it keeps telling me that there is a syntax error.

Here's the code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION check_verkoper (
    @var VARCHAR(32)
)
RETURNS bit
AS
BEGIN
    IF  (SELECT verkoper FROM gebruiker WHERE gebruikersnaam = @var) = 1
            BEGIN
                RETURN 1
            END
        RETURN 0
    END
go

ALTER TABLE verkoper
ADD CONSTRAINT CHK_verkoper CHECK(dbo.check_verkoper(gebruikersnaam) = 1);
GO
```

So it keeps telling me this error:

**Something went wrong in the syntax near:**

```
@var VARCHAR(32)
)
RETURNS bit
AS
BEGIN
    IF    (SELECT verkoper FROM gebruiker
```

**on line 2**

Can anyone help this student?

Comment: Your code is SQL Server code.  Your tag is MySQL.  That probably has something to do with your issues.

Comment: Yes,  i am programming in SQL server and then copying the query into phpmyadmin, is there something i should/could do?

Comment: . . phpadmin is most commonly used with MySQL.  SQL Server code is not going to work in general.  Use SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) for a SQL Server tool.

Comment: What's the Error actually you are facing?